# ios-Prevent reloading of cell in UITableView on scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, webview

I have implemented a `UIWebview` inside `UITableView`. When I scroll the table view the data reloads and there is some flickering of the `UIWebview`. This is because cells are reloaded whenever i scroll table view. I can save the state of cell or save the data of `UIWebview` in `NSMutableArray` for faster loading but i cannot save the cells. So how can i save the cell or prevent the reloading of cells again and again. I want those cells to be reloaded only once.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("videoCell") as! UITableViewCell

    //  var height = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame.size.height
            let linksCell = links[indexPath.row].videoLink
        let winksCell = links[indexPath.row]
            mutArray.insertObject(linksCell!, atIndex: indexPath.row)
    println(mutArray)


    if let webView = cell.viewWithTag(21) as? UIWebView {

        webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
        webView.scrollView.bounces = false
        var html = "<html><body><iframe src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/\(mutArray[indexPath.row])\" width=\"\(videoTable.frame.width - 16)\" height=\"200\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>"
        webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)

        //  println(linksCell.videoLink)
      //  println(html)
    }

    if let videoName = cell.viewWithTag(22) as? UILabel {
        videoName.text = winksCell.title
        videoName.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    }

    return cell

}
```

Comment: Although it is not recommended, you can achieve this by not using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`

Comment: Are you calling reloadData somewhere? If not, as Nishant said, remove dequeCell.

Comment: What is the alternative for dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier ?

Comment: Alex I am adding reloadData in viewDidLoad and i need to do that to display the data of tableview. How can i call the cells without dequeCell ?

Comment: You have to create the array of cells (for example in viewDidLoad) and then in cellForRowAtIndexPath just get the correct cell from array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: I did not test it. but give it a try:

replace:

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("videoCell") as! UITableViewCell
```

With

```
let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "videoCell")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help iAnurag but this thing did not work. It was showing a white screen. I used the debugger and found that cells are loaded but its contents are not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard then create a custom cell class
and get the cell with identifier inside

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
YourCustomeCell_Class *cell = (YourCustomeCell_Class *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCellIndentifier"]; 
return cell; 
}
```

Try it. Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: He does not want to deque the cell.

Comment: This will not work. I don't want to deque cells. I want to save the cells in memory.

Comment: You may add temporary check. 

Add the value of indexPath.row in a MutableArray every time on cellForRowAtIndexPath and match mutableArrayValue with the same same cell. 

if exist then do not call your code inside cellForRowAtIndexPath as you currently written.

Comment: @ekant i tried this also but in this the already loaded cells are loaded with the same cell content that was of the newly loaded cells.